# How to change the background color for individual rows in a collapsible content menu in liquid?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm just getting used to liquid and can't for the life of me figure out how to input the code to assign a color for each row in an accordion style collapsible menu.

I've managed to make the schema for the theme editor but can't get it to control the liquid.

I'm thinking it belongs where I've written [HERE] below but have no idea. If anyone could help I would super appreciate it!

Code below:

```
      {% endif %}
      <div class="grid__item">
        {%- for block in section.blocks -%}
```

[ HERE?? ]

```
        <div class="accordion{% if section.settings.layout == 'row' %} content-container color-{{ section.settings.row.color }} gradient{% endif %}" {{ block.shopify_attributes }}>
            <details id="Details-{{ block.id }}-{{ section.id }}"{% if section.settings.open_first_collapsible_row and forloop.first %} open{% endif %}>
              <summary id="Summary-{{ block.id }}-{{ section.id }}">
                {% render 'icon-accordion', icon: block.settings.icon %}
                <h3 class="accordion__title h4">
                  {{ block.settings.heading | default: block.settings.page.title }}
                </h3>
                {% render 'icon-caret' %}
              </summary>
              <div class="accordion__content rte" id="CollapsibleAccordion-{{ block.id }}-{{ section.id }}" role="region" aria-labelledby="Summary-{{ block.id }}-{{ section.id }}">
                {{ block.settings.row_content }}
                {{ block.settings.page.content }}
              </div>
            </details>
          </div>
        {%- endfor -%}
      </div>
```

Schema I created:

{
"type": "color",
"id": "row_color",
"default": "#FFFFFF",
"label": "Row Color",
"info": "Changes color for this individual row"
},

Comment: get block settings and use inline style into HTML to apply it to each row, like `style="background-color:block.settings.row_color;"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the section block schema data like this:

```
{{ block.settings.id }}
```

`id` is the ID you defined for the specific setting, in this case it would be `row_color`.

In conclusion:

```
{{ block.settings.row_color }} // Returns either your default value `#ffffff` or the one selected in the customizer
```

Comment: @EddieCarty you‘re welcome! I would really appreciate it if you can upvote and also accept my answer :)

Comment: For sure! Sorry! I'm new to stackoverflow. Answer accepted and when I have enough reputation points I will absolutely upvote. :) Have a great day David!